# Scala - best data structure to store a trie

Tags: scala

I want to store a trie in Scala.
The edges can have values `0` or `1`.
Each node will store an `Array[Int]` data type.

Can I use or extend an existing data structure to implement this?

Which existing data structure would be the best option?

Comment: You may find [this](http://mauricio.github.io/2015/01/06/building-a-prefix-tree-in-scala.html) useful for you.

Comment: I think you can use the standard `scala.collection.immutable.IntMap`: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.IntMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trie implementation is given at page 624 of Programming in Scala, 2nd Edition. The given example is backed by a Map

A snippet of the class signature :

```
 class PrefixMap[T] 
 extends mutable.Map[String, T] 
    with mutable.MapLike[String, T, PrefixMap[T]]
```